# Ubuntu 18.04LTS slow on a fast computer

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

I finally got around to switch from Windows to Linux and decided to install Ubuntu. The thing is, the UI seems to be lagging, most noticeable when I move a window or scroll.

I have a relatively powerful computer, that should definitely run gnome:

- i5-6600K @ 4.1GHz
- [GTX 950 (NVIDIA Driver 394.24.02)](https://pastebin.com/qFmyHKx6)
- [8GB of RAM](https://pastebin.com/zPF9JnUC)
- 256 SSD

If anyone can help me i would much appreciate it, as I really want to make Ubuntu my main OS!

EDIT: I have two 1080p monitors, and disabling one of them seams to improve performance by a lot, although not completely.